# Why does the Facebook Graph API give SSL errors in PHP?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ssl, curl

Every time I try to use the Facebook  Graph API in PHP 5.6 it gives me the following errors:

> Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in /home/xxx/public_html/api/v1/test.php

To begin with I was using the PHP SDK v4, but I'm now simply trying to connect to this URL:

> https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=XXXXX

using the following code:

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=XXXXX";
$result = file_get_contents($url);
$json_response = json_decode($result);
var_dump($json_response);
```

I have also tried every combination of manually setting the SSL mode and using cURL that I can find on Google but it always gives me the same error. Is there a server setting that I need to change/enable or am I making a simple mistake?

EDIT:
When I try to set the cipher mode to TLS 1.2 using cURL it gives the same error:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array( $ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => 'TLSv1_2',
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true
) );
$output = curl_exec( $ch );
echo $output;

echo 'error:' . curl_error( $ch );

curl_close($ch);
```

> error:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

Comment: which php version are you using? When I was using openssl with the php 5.4, I found out the openssl is buggy (openssl sign and verify don't work)..
php 5.5 worked great for me, haven't tested with php 5.6

Comment: You are trying to connect to Facebook using SSL 2 or SSL 3. You have to use TLS

Comment: I'm using 5.6. I just swapped to 5.5 and it doesn't give any errors but the output is NULL.

Comment: WizKid please see edit I have made

Comment: @JoeEwing Any success ? because same error I get it...If you have any trick to handle this please revert.